# RegExp incorrectly invalidate user unput

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Already spent 2 days on this very basic regex
.I want it to validate inputs exactly of 4 characters.And only upper & lower case Letters.No digits or special symbols.But it is invalidating everything including the correct ones.
Can't catch the issue.
Please help.Code below:---

thanks

pkj

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>
 RegEx Test
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
     <P>
        <FORM action="cgi-bin/page2.py"
           Type something:<input  Id="usrInput" TYPE="text" VALUE="" onblur="chkInput()">
                  <input Id="ts" TYPE="number" NAME="ts" value=0> 
                  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Go" >
        </FORM>
    </P>
     <script>
        function chkInput(){
         var myRgx=new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]{4}$/);   
         var input=document.getElementById("usrInput").innerHTML;  
          var rslt=myRgx.test(input);
          alert(rslt)
        }

     </script>
</BODY>
```

Comment: Seems to work. However you need to make sure the input is exact four characters. Since your regexp doesn't match otherwise

Comment: Need to use `value` property of input element instead of innerHTML to get the value in the input box. See the working snippet in answer

Answer (score 1):

To pick value of input type text use `.value` and not `innerHtml`

Working Snippet:

```js
function chkInput() {
  var myRgx = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]{4}$/);
  var input = document.getElementById("usrInput").value;
  var rslt = myRgx.test(input);
  console.log(rslt)
}
```

```html
<FORM action="cgi-bin/page2.py">
  Type something:
  <input Id="usrInput" TYPE="text" VALUE="" onblur="chkInput()">
  <input Id="ts" TYPE="number" NAME="ts" value=0>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Go">
</FORM>
```

Comment: "To pick value of input type text use .value and not innerHtml" this is the bullet.SOLVED

Comment: @Jayk : Good to hear that your problem is solved. :)